# Element ID

Tags: javascript

I'm trying my best to make my jQuery / AJAX scripts, but sometimes I run into some problems, like right now, so I'm seeking some help!

On a game page of my website, in the comment box, you find a little "Like (0)" link right there, and when you click, well it actually adds +1 to the comment, without any page reload.

On the PHP side, all goes well, but in the javascript part, I got trouble with the ID's. The original code I had contained this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("like").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

Where I'm having issues is the `document.getElementById("like")` part. Since I have many comments, I deceided to give them a different ID to solve the problem, so comment 1 will have

```
<span id="like1">The +like stuff here</span>
```

and so on (like2, like3, etc)

But in my JS code (I already did some Actionscript, and was using the evenement.currentTarget) I cant figure out how to do it. (So if I click like10, it will update the like10 span box.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I dont know if I'm clear enough, but thanks anyways!

Comment: Is the question how to get the target of an event or something else?

Comment: My question is more like, when you click the link inside span id= like3 well it sends the request and then updates the same span. because if i just put span id= like, any span i click will just update the first one

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it:

```
  function getComment(i)
  {
    ...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         document.getElementById("like"+i).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will cause a race condition. Since AJAX is *asynchroneous*, you can't guarantee that the value of `i` hasn't changed between the request being sent and its completion (in which case, the wrong ID will be updated)

Comment: Got any solution to that, which is guranteed to update the right id?

Comment: @Daniel: Depends on the context.  I made it into a function to avoid the potential for that problem.  If you were to put my original code inside a loop, it would have that problem - but inside its own function, it's fine.

Comment: could you explain this abit more to me? how do i get the actualy game id into that i

Comment: I'm a little confused about the context of your application, but I would guess you might have a link and set its click event:
link1.onclick = function(){ getComment(1); };

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function handle_click(event)
{
  var evt = event || window.event; // IE doesn't pass along an event object
  var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement; // IE and W3C differ on what property to use
  var id_to_update = ... // figure out which ID needs updating (perhaps based on target)

  var request = setup_xhr(); // dummy function that sets up an XHR object
  request.open(...);
  request.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
      update_like(id_to_update, request.responseText)
    }
  }
}

function update_like(target, new_value)
{
  document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = new_value;
}

document.getElementById('[id of element]').addEventListener('click', handle_click); // only covers the W3C event model, but you get the idea
```

When the event listener function sets up the AJAX request, you can have it specify which element will be updated, so when it completes it updates the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are using jQuery, sounds like you should be using it's `$.ajax` and `.bind()` functions instead of native js.